# How to retrieve images for a place using HERE Geocoding and Search api?

Tags: here-api

I am doing a POC for one of my projects using HERE Geocoding and Search api. I want to search places around a given latitude and longitude and need details of those places including an image/images.
I am using `https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=47.80049,3.57119&limit=2&categories=700-7600-0000,700-7600-0116&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}` which returns all details of places but without image related details.
So I tried to use `https://lookup.search.hereapi.com/v1/lookup?id=here:pds:place:276u33dc-2ba407e1181849c9a761a336b8df1805&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}` where `id` is returned as one of the attributes in response of previous `/browse` call, but again this returns same details (without image) as retuned by `/browse` api.
I tried to follow this documentation https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/migration_guide/migration-places/topics-api/place-details.html but it doesn't help much.
So is there a way to retrieve image/images for places using HERE Geocoding and Search api. I would be grateful if some one can share their experience or guide me to correct documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Media Type attributes are currently not returned in GS7 apis. The same is told in the below document.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/migration_guide/migration-places/topics-api/place-details.html